# W3schools says "formenctype" only works for "submit" and "image" type, while everyone else says it's used for "file" type. Is w3school wrong?

Tags: html, css

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes_form.asp

As you can see, they say that the "formencstyle" attribute only works for the following input types: "image" and "submit", but everyone on stackoverflow says that, formenctype="multipart/form-data" is meant to be used for "file" types of the "input" element. So, why does w3schools then claim that that attribute can only work for "submit" and "image"? Are they outdated again?

Comment: It seems like an error, as you can use it for any file you want, not just images.

Comment: Why am i getting so many dislikes? I think that's a pretty legitimate question.

Comment: Maybe because it's not really a coding question...

Comment: But I thought it to be clear in my views that's all, I really apologize if I made anyone feel that way. Sorry, I didn't meant that at all. I ask the community to forgive me, if they feels that I did  it either for my own benefit or for countering someone else's downvote

Comment: @TaishoMori - There's not much wrong with the question. But asking "why does [third-party] do X?" is not well-framed as we can't possibly know the motivation behind that third party. It would gave been better if you had framed your questions as "X says this, Y says that (with references *to both*, because the exact wording is often critical in such questions), is one incorrect, or how are they both true?

Comment: Good point, but i still feel people would've disliked it for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up things.

The "encoding type" is how the form should be encoded when it is sent to the server. This is something that applies to the form as a whole. It can't be applied to individual elements. If you want to upload a file using the `<input type="file">` element, your form (as a whole) needs to be submitted using the `multipart/form-data` encoding.

You can define that encoding type by using the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute on a `<form>` element or by using the `formenctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute on a submit button.

The `formenctype` attribute on a submit button overrides the `enctype` of the `<form>` element when a form is submitted using that submit button.

```html
<form method="POST">
  <input type="submit" 
         value="Clicking me submits the form using the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding method">
  <input type="submit" 
         formenctype="multipart/form-data"
         value="Clicking me submits the form using the `multipart/form-data` encoding method">
</form>
```

You can't apply the `formenctype` to a file element, because a file element is not a submit button and the encoding type doesn't apply to individual elements.

In this case W3Schools is not wrong. The `formenctype` is used on submit buttons and there are two kinds of submit buttons: `<input type="image">` and `<input type="submit">`.

Comment: This makes no sense. You keep saying that if you want to upload a file, you have to use the multipart/form-data, which is used how? By saying "formenctype="multipart/form-data". It's a value of the formenctype attribute. But w3school says that formenctype attribute only works for two input types - "submit" and "image" NOT file. So how else can you upload a file other than using "type="file" which then means that formenctype is used for type="file" too, and not just submit and image. Am i missing something?

Comment: @TaishoMori The encoding method applies to the whole form, not one element. Either you send the whole form encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or you send the whole form as `multipart/form-data`. It is not something that you can specify for every (file) element separately. By using `<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">` you tell the form that everything within it needs to be encoded as `multipart/form-data`, including the file elements. The same applies to the `formenctype`, but then you to set the encoding type depending on the submit button you click.

Comment: That's not true. The encoding method we are discussing and all these other attributes taught in w3school are for individual child-elements within a form element. Formmethod changes the method by which the data is to be send only for that one element. That's what it says, and that's what happens when you try. You can set the form to be "get" and then have two buttons, one default, another one using the formmethod="post". The formenctype is also for the individual child element only. If you want to change the enctype of the whole form, you type enctype in the form parent element.

Comment: Anyway, i must therefore conclude that w3schools have made a mistake, or are using outdated rules, since formenctype multipart/form-data applies to files as well as image and submit types. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @TaishoMori I'm not making this up. If you don't believe it, [check the official HTML specification for yourself](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-submission-2). W3Schools is often wrong and I wouldn't recommend using it, but for this specific case it is correct. You can also use your browser's developer tools to check the actual network calls and see the content type of those using the different attributes.

Comment: I didn't see where in your link does it say that formmethod, formenctype or formtarget apply to the entire form, and not the single element it is written in. I have tested this, and it works exactly as they say it should. You can try it yourself. Make a parent form element with the attribute method="get", then add two buttons along with some input type element. On the first button, don't add anything, on the second, add the attribute formethod="post", and then try both buttons. You'll see that the first one submits the form with "get", the second with "post" method.

Comment: @TaishoMori In your test you are absolutely right. If you put `formethod="post"` on the submit button, the whole form is submitted via the POST HTTP method. Not just the button that you click. If you add `<input name="x" type="text">` to your form, that input field will also be submitted using the POST method, even though you don't add `formethod="post"` to that element specifically. The same applies to `formenctype`. If you submit a form with the submit button using `formenctype="multipart/form-data"`, then your file elements will also be submitted using that encoding type.

Comment: You can try [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qL4vrwds/) as an example. (Use Firefox, because Chrome doesn't really show the actual request body.) Open the Network tab in the developer tools, submit the form with an image, select the request that was initiated by that submission and hit the "Request" tab. There you will see that the first form will only submit the file name where the bottom form will actually submit the file content as well.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It seems that i got confused thinking that the formmethod applies to the child-element, rather than the parent form element. The attribute formmethod when added to a child-element inside a form parent only rewrites the parent form's method. The whole form gets submitted, not the button itself. You were right, i'm sorry. Although i still don't see how w3school is not wrong, since they claimed the formenctype attribute only works for type:submit and image, when it clearly works for type:file as well.

Comment: @TaishoMori - What you can't do is have `<input type="file" formenctype="multipart/form-data">` That won't change the enc type of the form. That's what w3schools means. Note that you *can* do `<button type="submit" formenctype="multipart/form-data"></button>`, but w3schools is still not wrong for omitting that, because it is specifically talking about the input element there.

Comment: I see. So, for submitting files, i have to add the attribute enctype on the parent element itself, i.e. the form element, and it won't work if i add it on the child-element? By the way, w3school did not omit about the submit type. They said it only works for submit and image, which is apparently correct.

Comment: @TaishoMori You only need to use `formenctype` if you have multiple submit buttons within the same form and you want to use a different encoding type depending on the submit button that is clicked. That situation is very rare (I never encountered it). In any other case you can forget about `formenctype` just use the `enctype` on the `<form>` element.